# winappdbg debug + api hooking + cpu precent

Tags: python

i am using winappdbg debug , creating an eventhandler that is hooking the createfile function on the processes i attach to the debugger. i couldnt use "loop" func because this way the debugger is unstopable, so i use other functions. after deataching and looking how many createfile calls occured , i am trying to get cpu precent of the processes and they are automaticaly going to 0. i think its because of the debugger but not sure why

while True:
        hooked = []

```
    eventhandelerobject = hooking4.EventReciever()
    debugger = Debug(eventhandelerobject,False)


    """hooking"""
    for procid in psutil.pids():
        if not whitelist5.inlist(procid):
            print procid
            try:
                debugger.attach(procid)
                hooked.append(procid)
                print "Initialized!"+str(procid)

                errorfile.write("Initialized!"+str(procid))

            except Exception as ex:
                print ex
                errorfile.write(str(ex)+str(procid))
    run_time = 60

    start = time.clock()

    time_passed = 10
    print "start"
    while time.clock()-start<60:
        #############################
        if time.clock()-start>time_passed:
            for procid in psutil.pids():
                if not whitelist5.inlist(procid) and procid not in hooked:
                    try:
                        debugger.attach(procid)
                        hooked.append(procid)
                        print "Initialized!"+str(procid)
                    except:
                        continue
                ######################################

            time_passed+=10

        try:
            #debugger.next()
            event = debugger.wait(1000)
            debugger.dispatch(event)
            debugger.cont(event)
        except:
            continue
    print "stop"



    print "part2"

    over_cpu_mem_id = cpu_mem4.dangerous_cpu_and_mem(0,0)
    counter = hooking_count.Count.counterdict
    print "counter:"
    print counter
    sorted_counter = sorted(counter.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    if over_cpu_mem_id >= 1:
        if registry4.manage() and not whitelist5.inlist(over_cpu_mem_id):
            print "cpu+registry , not in whitelist"
            pid_being_suspected = over_cpu_mem_id
            if file4.mannge(filesnumber, timeinseconds):
                print "files are changing..."


                if len(sorted_counter)>0:
                    most_createfiles = sorted_counter[0][1]
                    pid = sorted_counter[0][0]
                    #############################
                    exe = psutil.Process(pid).exe()
                    print exe
                    cpuexe = psutil.Process(over_cpu_mem_id).exe()
                    print cpuexe
                    ######################

                    if most_createfiles >= 100 and pid == over_cpu_mem_id:
                        process_control5.process_dealing(pid)
        elif pid_being_suspected >0 and len(sorted_counter)>0:
            most_createfiles = sorted_counter[0][1]
            pid = sorted_counter[0][0]
            if most_createfiles >= 100 and pid == pid_being_suspected:
                process_control5.process_dealing(pid)
            pid_being_suspected = -1



    print "no danger"


    hooking_count.Count.reset_dict()


    time.sleep(10)
    debugger.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure as I never tried to get the CPU usage of a debugged process, but I suspect it's because when you try and measure that, the debugged process is paused. Generally when your debugger takes control, the debugged process is frozen, therefore you will always see 0% usage.

If that's the case, the solution is rather complicated. You'll have to write two scripts (or alternatively a single script, but running twice). One that debugs the targets, collects all the process IDs and the files being open. And another one measuring the CPU usage, in parallel.